# Is there an official extension for hgFlow in TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using Mercurial with TortoiseHG for version control, but I've recently installed SourceTree to have a look at it. There I've known about [the Flow extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FlowExtension) and looks quite interesting.

So I'm wondering if there's any more-or-less-official extension to add support for hgflow in TortoiseHG. I've come across [thgflow](https://bitbucket.org/peso/thgflow), but I don't know if it works, if the project is still active, if there are other alternatives...

Any insight?

Comment: Ok, [thgflow seems to be abandoned](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CACAoc6_bGSyPkApd2b7jKy1GTCSijsNoA3DqyzbTEf4-2fvijw%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=tortoisehg-discuss)

Answer (score 2):

SourceTree's GUI for [hgflow](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home) provides only 50% of the extension's features. Try the command line if you can. The extension is very nice and easy to use.

Comment: a nice doc to it: http://epics-pvdata.sourceforge.net/hgflow/using_hgflow_20130828.html